# SPGridView Filtering for taxonomy columns

Tags: managed-metadata, filter, spgridview

I am displaying some sharepoint 2013 list data in SPGridView and I am using SPDataSource for binding list data with grid.
The problem is with managed metadata columns filtering. In filter of managed metadata columns, instead of term name, it is coming as TermName|TermGUID. Besides that my column is allows multiple values too. 
Could anyone help.

PS: If I use DataTable instead of SPDataSource, I can fix this issue by formatting the values first and after that binding it to grid. But I want to use SPDataSource as it makes other things simple.

EDIT: If we override GetCallbackResult() method of SPGridView, we can edit the filter values. But is there any way we can recognize, which column we are applying filtering on (in GetCallbackResult method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used XSLTListView WebPart to solve this issue. Not able to find anything else.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the solution or explain more precisely how did you do ?